# AHK and drive safety when constantly writing to disk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, autohotkey

First of all am fairly new to all this, so please bear with me.

I am in a situation where I need to constantly write the contents of a variable to an INI file located on the `C:` drive.

By constant I mean anything from 1 Second to 200ms. No parallel writing. Just one file per cycle.

- How safe would this be for the drives health?
- Would it speed up its deterioration considerably?
- Between SSD and traditional hard drives, which type are known to be optimal for programs that need to constantly write small files and also reading on demand?

I did some reading, for example this thread here [Why you shouldn't use FileAppend to continuously write to the disk - AutoHotkey Community](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=61853) discourages this kind of thing.

Comment: Your problem description lacks any details to evaluate the amount of wear your storage. You do not state how many times your write operaton wil be performed. You just state that one lasts from 200 ms to 1 second. Are there lots of parallel write operations? The article you read does not discourage anything. It just makes you aware to ensure that your write operations are programmed in a efficient, less wear-generating manner.

Comment: @r2d3 My apologies, to answer your question, the file will be written to disk ones every second to 200ms. There will not be parallel operation just one file per cycle.

Comment: Is there any particular issue you have not mentioned yet why you are focussing on that very special issue?

Comment: What is AHK? Not using abbreviations makes your question available to a broader range of possible and helps search engines.

Comment: When your writing to said INI file are you changing existing values, or are you appending to said file?  Does the file continuously grow larger because your appending to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a small RAM drive, and use that so you don't have to do that much writing to the hard drive.

Then if I need to I would use mklink to make a shortcut to said file on the C drive.

If necessary I could backup said file to the hard drive say once an hour if you need to retain the data long term.